# Adding "Featured Posts" to my blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, blogs

I am trying to add a featured post feature to my Ruby on Rails Blog. So far I have added a `featured_post` column to my `post` table and it passes a `1` if the check box is selected and `0` if not.

Now I am attempting to pull out these posts by doing the following:

/views/posts/index.html.erb

```
  <% @featured_post.each do |post| %>
    <%= post.title %>
  <% end %>
```

And in the posts_controller.rb I am doing the following in the `index` action:

```
@featured_post = Post.all
```

Obviously this brings in all the post titles which is not what I want. I am assuming I have to add something to the controller to all for this but not sure what that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your post model, write this

```
named_scope :featured,:conditions => {:featured_post => true }
```

write this in your controller

```
@featured_posts = Post.featured
```

and in view use this,

```
<% @featured_posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= post.title %>
  <% end %>
```

now you should get all the featured posts.

Comment: I get this error: undefined method `where' for #<Class:0x102c748d8>

Comment: Which version of rails are you using?